# Jfilechooser select multiple files but not directories

Tags: java, jfilechooser

How can I let the user choose one or multiple files or
only one directory?

The below settings will also allow selecting multiple dirs
as well as files and directories at the same time and I want to prevent that.

```
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you setup ProportyChangeListener as in example below:

```
        final JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
        c.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        c.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        c.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILES_CHANGED_PROPERTY.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    File[] selectedFiles = c.getSelectedFiles();
                    if (selectedFiles.length > 1) {
                        File f=c.getSelectedFile();
                        if (f.isDirectory())
                            c.setSelectedFiles(new File[] {f});
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        c.showDialog(null,"Apply");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(c.getSelectedFiles()));
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I let the user choose one or multiple files or only one directory?

To enable one or multiple choice use `chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);`

To enable file or directory choice use `chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);`

To enable file only use `chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);`

To enable directory only use `chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);`

**For example:** only multiple files:

```
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
```

**For example:** just one file:

```
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
```

Comment: Thanks but not really what I was asking for. I want to know if it possible to allow only multiple files (or just one file) but not multiple directories.

Comment: ...Again let me be even more clear. The filechooser opens..Then I want to be able ctrl+click for multiple files but not for multiple directories ...it there was a method it would be called chooser.setMultiSelectionForDirectoriesEnabled(false); and chooser.setMultiSelectionForFilesEnabled(true);  :)